# jquery: toggle children onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, parent-child

what js/jquery code would make below list toggle children when clicking "+" ?

```
<ul>  
<li id="1" parent="0"><a href="#">1</a></li>  
    <li id="2" parent="0"><a href="#"> + </a><a href="#">2</a>  
        <ul parent="2">  
            <li id="23" parent="2"><a href="#">2.1</a></li>  
            <li id="50" parent="2"><a href="#"> + </a><a href="#">2.2</a>  
                <ul parent="50">  
                    <li id="123" parent="50"><a  href="#">2.50.1</a></li>  
                </ul>  
            </li>  
        </ul>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) with [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$("ul a:contains( + )").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9DPTq/1/).  Note though your IDs and attributes are invalid, you may want to use [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) here.  Also, I suggest giving those `+` links a class, to make the selector *much* more efficient, for example:

```
<a href="#" class=".toggle"> + </a>
```

Then binding like this:

```
$("ul a.toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$("ul a:contains('+')").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings("ul").show();
});
```